# Can I choose the order in which these effects trigger in Yu-Gi-Oh?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Suppose that I have [Yubel - Terror Incarnate](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yubel_-_Terror_Incarnate) on the field and I normal summon [Inaba White Rabbit](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Inaba_White_Rabbit).

Both of them have effects that trigger at the end phase:

- Yubel - Terror Incarnate: destroys all other monsters.
- Inaba White Rabbit: returns itself to the hand.

In which order do I execute them? Can I choose?

I would like to return Inaba White Rabbit to my hand before it gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In which order do I execute them? Can I choose?

Yes, you can choose.

Both effects are mandatory, so you *have* to activate them eventually.

As they both happen at the same time, and because it's your turn you chose which effect goes first, and each one goes in a separate chain (naturally you'll want Inaba to go first).

For reference, lets consider [this wiki page](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Simultaneous_Effects_Go_On_Chain), with my emphasis:

> ... effects that activate "During the […] Phase…" or "At the end of the […] Phase…", such as "Gladiator Beast" monsters. Instead, **each effect activates as Chain Link 1 of its own Chain.**

Furthermore, on that same page they indicate the following (which is based from the [Official Rulebook](https://www.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/SD_RuleBook_EN_V10.pdf) p. 50, 3rd part):

> If multiple effects fall into the same category [mandatory/optional], the player that activates them chooses the order in which they are activated

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like this is a bug with Duel Links then...

Comment: @PedroA i believe duel links works around the basis of whichever was on field first activates first, as none of these effects are quick effects yubel will activate on duel links first. however in an actual game you can choose the order in which you resolve the effects, so in this case resolve inaba, then resolve yubel